# set google cloud storage bucket access logs in java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to enable logging against a bucket on GCS using the java sdk. Essentially, I want to implement the equivalent of the gsutil command : `gsutil logging set on -b gs://logging-bucket  -o AccessLog  gs://mycompanybucket` as specified in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/logging#get_1) . I have tried to call the command line via java code but this always hands forever.

```
public static void checkLoggingBuckets(ArrayList<String> cloudbuckets) throws IOException {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            ArrayList<String> bucketList = cloudbuckets;
            try {
                for (String st: bucketList) {
                    String command = "cmd /c cmd.exe gsutil logging set on -b gs://logs-bucket-2019  -o AccessLog  gs://";
                    System.out.println("checking for bucket "  + st);
                    Process proc = rt.exec(command + st);

            int result = proc.waitFor();

            System.out.println("Process exit code: " + result);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Result:");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
                }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the Java client, there is no need to start a subprocess with `gsutil` command :

```java
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
Bucket bucket = storage.get("mycompanybucket");

BucketInfo.Logging logging = BucketInfo.Logging.newBuilder()
    .setLogBucket("logging-bucket")  // -b parameter of gsutil logging set command
    .setLogObjectPrefix("AccessLog") // -o parameter of gsutil logging set command
    .build();

bucket = bucket.toBuilder()
    .setLogging(logging)
    .build()
    .update();
```

*Source* : https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/6981#issuecomment-561648354.

Comment: awesome ! it works well for me, the documentation need to be improved !